# ASP.NET memory leak

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem with a memory leak in a very large ASP.NET application.  After about 24 hours of usage (sometimes a lot more) an OutOfMemory exception is thrown.  Therefore I am trying to understand how managed memory works in .NET.  When does an ASP.NET application throw an OutOfMemory exception?  The server has a lot of RAM and there is always plenty of memory left when an OutOfMemory exception is thrown.  I understand the difference between virtual memory and physical memory.  How much memory does the W3WP process have to consume before an OutOfMemory exception is thrown? Is there a setting somewhere e.g. in the Machine.Config file? The ASP.NET process is never recycled.

Comment: Your application pool define the maximum memory and the actions that are fired if the limit is reached. So seek your properties there to take short actions. In general you need to check your code that you initalize and release alle resources you use to prevent permanent grow of memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment above: Check your main resource usages and at the end of use make sure you use .Dispose() to release it.

For the memory usage go to the IIS manager, open the tree and navigate to your application pools. Edit advanced properties from the pool your website use and check/set the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

I used ANTS memory profiler. That will help you find the place where code caused menory leaks. You can also create user defined performance monitor in the perfmon tool.

This worked for me. Let me know if you need more help